# How to Add starUML plugin into Eclipse(juno)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, staruml

Please help me to add the StarUML plugin into Eclipse IDE.

i'm searching in Google but i could not fine any link for this.

please help give the url to add the eclipse ...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Usually it should be enough to put the plugins into /plugins and the feature(s) to the /features folder. You may benefit from Eclipse internal provisioning by putting it in the /dropins folder. These folder is monitored by eclipse and will guarantee a proper installation.
Does starUML not come with a update-site link?

Answer (score 0):

Start Eclipse > Select Help > Install Software > Available Software Tab > Add Site > Give any name and Enter this URL

http://downloads.myeclipseide.com/downloads/products/eworkbench/helios/enterprise-earlyaccess/

Wait for few seconds and select all the options that appears for installation and click Next.